# Software Licence Agreement: Does our spec abide by the licence

Tags: licensing, mit-license

Can you determine if this Open Source Winforms UI Library licence allows companies to use this code in a commercial software application?

> The MIT License (MIT)
>
> Copyright (c) 2011 Sven Walter, http://github.com/viperneo
>
> **Permission is hereby granted**, free of charge, to any person obtaining
>   a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
>   "Software"), **to deal in the Software without restriction**, including
>   without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
>   distribute, sublicense, **and/or sell copies of the Software**, and to
>   permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, **subject to
>   the following conditions**:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
>   included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
>
> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
>   EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
>   MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.
>   IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY
>   CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT,
>   TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE
>   SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

[Licence can be found here](https://github.com/viperneo/winforms-modernui/blob/master/README.md#license)

I can see that it gives permission to use the code in commercial products but it is subject to conditions. We intend to use the UI (a Windows 8 looking interface) in a simple application that will convert Civil Engineering survey files from one format to another which maybe sold commercially in the future.

Those in the know, do our intentions fall within the lines of the license rules?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The conditions are listed immediately below, and they are pretty straight forward. Are you including the copyright notice and permission notice in your software? Are you willing to accept the face that there are no warranties for the usage of the software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The license you cited is a common open source license. It is one of the 'permissive' type licenses which allows using the code in propriety software.  In short, you're probably fine to use the code in your application.

That said, this is the internet, I am not a lawyer, I am not your lawyer, this is not legal advice, blah, blah.